# Passing IEnumerable<Object> to MVC view and casting to strongly typed object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a requirement to pass an `IEnumerable<Object>` to an MVC view and have the view cast this to a strongly typed object and display it accordingly.

This appears to be having a performance impact vs. passing it down as a IEnumerable of MyCustomObject.

```
foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    var current = (MyCustomObject) item;
    <p>@current.Submitted</p>
}
```

My questions are

1. Should I cast the entire IEnumerable of Objects to IEnumerable of MyCustomObject?
2. How can I improve the performance of this operation?
3. If this is not good practice, what's the best way to pass a "variable" type for my Items collection, which could be a collection of any type of custom object?

Comment: why do you have that requirement? it seems silly. not to mention a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I don't think you really have a performance problem here. That's very unlikely. Have you verified this with a profiler?

Comment: Yes never cast in the view, the view is dull and should use little logic where possible

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you would like to do with the `IEnumerable` once in the view? What and when to cast depend entirely on this.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. What's the best way to pass a "variable" type for my Items collection, which could be a collection of any type of custom object?

Comment: are your models going to have common properties? if so, use a base class or an interface.

Comment: They won't have common properties.

Comment: Why is this a requirement? Like stated before, seems silly and kind of more clunky than anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, you could use Cast on the entire collection:

```
foreach (var item in Model.Items.Cast<MyCustomObject>()){}
```

If your types will all inherit from a base type, say MyCustomObject, then your model should specify this, e.g.

```
public class MyViewModel<T> where T : MyCustomObject, new() 
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

You would need to ensure that any types you wished to add to your items collection inherited from the base `MyCustomObject` type

Comment: Why cast when the source should be strongly defined?

Answer (score 2):

Use a List pass this to the model, then it is strongly defined

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(){

MyModel model = new MyModel();
model.list = //get list from source

return View(model);

}
```

**Model**

```
public List<MyCustomObject> list {get; set;}
```

Comment: It isn't the List that makes it strongly defined, it's the type of the generic argument. This is true regardless of whether you use List or IEnumerable (the base type for List)